# how to assign to a variable the reference towards a key in a hash

Tags: perl, data-structures, tree

I need to traverse a binary tree. The values of the tree are located in a hash.

I used the `Data::Dumper` module to visualize the hash, but the pointer (the variable that shows where in the tree we are located when we travel) won't accept the reference to the tree.

This is a simplified version of my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;

# ID = id of the nod in the tree     
# 'v' = value of the nod  
# 'p' = id of the father nod  
# '+' = son of the nod ( bigger than father)
# '-' = son of the nod ( smaller than father)  

my $tree = {

    'id' => 0,
    'v' => 12,
    '+' => { 
            'id' => 1,
            'p' => 12,
            'v' => 18,
        }
};

my $pointer = $tree -> { '+' } -> { 'id' };      

# travel trough the tree
while(exists  ($pointer -> {'p'}))      # while $pointer will have a father
  $noeud_courant =  $noeud_courant->{'p'};  # give $pointer the value of the father i                   
}

say "value of the first father = $pointer -> { 'v' } ";
```

Comment: You seems to miss the openng bracket of your while loop {. Secondly AFAIK you should not have space between the variable and the reference arrow ($pointer ->). Are there any error messages? Also: in your while loop you should change the value of $pointer, because right now it is an infinite loop. I think a $pointer = $pointer->{+} or $pointer = $pointer->{p} should be there. I have too little info to say exactly what is wrong.

Comment: You also don't seem to have a structure that maps `id` numbers back to actual hash references.  Aside from `$tree->{+}`, the links in your structure are all in terms of `id` numbers, not references.  You need a separate hash, say `%id_to_hash`, whose keys are `id` numbers and whose values are references to the different hashes in your tree if you want to build links that way.

Comment: the *first* problem here is that you are not saying `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a node `$n` with `$n->{p}` equal to 12, you want to be able to find from this the node `$p` that has `$p->{id}` equal to 12.  But your program doesn't contain anything that would allow it to easily find the node `$p`.  You need to add this.

One way to do this is to assemble an *index* that maps ID numbers to tree nodes.  An index is just an array where `$index[$n]` is the tree node whose ID number is `$n`. This function, run on the root of your tree, builds an index for it:

```
sub index_tree {
  my ($root, $index) = @_;
  $index->[$root->{id}] = $root;
  for my $sub_node (values %$root) {
    next unless ref $sub_node eq "HASH";
    index_tree($sub_node, $index);
  }
}
```

To use this, call:

```
my @index;
index_tree($tree, \@index);
```

Now `@index` is your index.  Suppose you have `$pointer = 1` as in your example, and you want to trace back up to the root.  You could use:

```
while (defined $pointer) {
  my $node = $index[$pointer];
  $pointer = $node->{p};
}
```

At each step through the loop, `$pointer` is the ID of the current node and `$node` is the current node itself.

If the space of IDs is sparse, it would be appropriate to use a hash instead of an array for the index.

---

Instead of storing the index in a separate array, you could replace the `p` entries with pointers back to the parent nodes themselves:

```
sub fix_parent_pointers {
  my ($root) = @_;
  for my $sub_node (values %$root) {
    next unless ref $sub_node eq "HASH";
    $sub_node->{p} = $root;
    fix_parent_points($sub_node);
  }
}

fix_parent_pointers($tree);
```

After doing this, each node, except the root, has its entire parent node stored in its `p` element in place of the ID number.  If `$node` is a node, you can now trace back up to the root by doing this:

```
while (exists $node->{p}) {
  $node = $node->{p};
}
```

The major drawback of this technique is that Perl will no longer be able to garbage-collect your tree when you are done with it. This can be avoided by weakening the parent reference with [`Scalar::Util::weaken()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar%3a%3aUtil#weaken-REF) so it does not obstruct garbage collection:

```
use Scalar::Util qw/weaken/;
...
$sub_node->{p} = $root;
weaken($sub_node->{p});
...
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the solution to the problem with circular references. — I also wanted to express my gratitude for writing (and making available freely) the HOP book, and some slides of your talks. The clear explanations of functional techniques got me started with functional programming, and unlocked the “true power” of Perl for me. Thanks!